# ViewDidDisappear for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I need to know when my UITableViewCell is being removed inside my UITableViewCell for invalidate a timer.

What method is called just before the cell disappear  (just like ViewDidDisappear in the lifecycle of a viewController) ?

I want to do it invalidate my NSTimer inside my UITableViewCell.

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:**

I start my NSTimer inside layoutSubview in my UITableViewCell

```
 var timer = NSTimer()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    println("in layoutSubViews")
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Post some code where timer has declared.

Comment: Cells get reused and might not get released as long as the table view is alive. Only thing that you can do is,  invalidate the timer of the cell, whenever it is being fetched via the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier call.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such method for `UIView`.

Comment: As @Shripada said in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` first check if timer have any memory , if it does invalidate it. If not, initial new timer. And when you are about to leave your table , fetch all cell (tableview class has a method for that) and invalidate respected timers.

Comment: I edited my post with some code

Comment: if I use my UITableViewController then I've got a tons of possible solution , I'm trying to put everything inside My UITableViewCell . It's not fully needed but I think it would be a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no method called just before a Cell disappear that will suit my problem I used the TableView to invalidate the timer .

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepareForReuse() on the cell.
Not sure exactly when this is called but it's before it's reused.
In you cell it would look something like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    timer.invalidate()
}
```